# NotImplementedError: Axes3D currently only supports the aspect argument 'auto'. You passed in 'equal'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

[I was following this tutorial](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basemap3d.html)

I tried to run these codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

map = Basemap()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

'''
ax.azim = 270
ax.elev = 90
ax.dist = 5
'''

ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.35))

plt.show()
```

#### However I have gotten these error:

```
NotImplementedError: Axes3D currently only supports the aspect argument 'auto'. You passed in 'equal'.
```

```
AttributeError: 'LineCollection' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection'
```

Any suggestions in resolving this?
Is this because of my environment; my packages versions causing issues?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and fixed it by adding `fix_aspect=Flase` in `Basemap` as below.

```
map = Basemap(fix_aspect=False)
```